# Angular virtual scroll shows wrong information when including angular component in item's HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am using the built in virtual scroll in angular like this:

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="75" class="vs-viewport">
    <app-chatitemtemplate
        *cdkVirtualFor="let item of myChatList; let i = index"
        class="vs-item"
        [item]="{
            item: item,
            indexInList: i
        }">
    </app-chatitemtemplate>
</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

The username of app-chatitemtemplate has recycling issues, i.e. it shows the wrong names after scrolling. That is because the HTML of app-chatitemtemplate looks somehow like this:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="{{ profileImgURL }}">

    <div class="itemSecondWrapper">
        <div class="item-bar-wrapper">

            <!-- NOTE THIS -->
            <app-usernametemplate 
                [verifiedInp]="item.verified"
                [nameInp]="item.name">
            </app-usernametemplate>

            <div class="timestamp item-bar-end-wrapper">
                {{ getTimeString() }}
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- ... -->
```

All other information such as profile image, timestamp or last message is displayed correctly, just not the app-usernametemplate. So I tried to remove the `app-usernametemplate` and replace in with the "raw underlying html" of it, and now its working. So the recycling issue arises from using an angular component within the item HTML. How can I fix this?

---

Here is the code how I pass the data to `app-chatitemtemplate`:

```
private _item: any = null;
@Input()
set item(value: any) {
    this._item = value.item;
    this.indexInList = value.indexInList;

    this.itemChanged();
}

get item(): any {
    return this._item;
}

// needed for recycling reasons
itemChanged() {
    // calculate all information etc ...
}

// ...
```

---

**Edit:**
I was able to find a "work-around" based on other SO threads, which is setting `templateCacheSize: 0` in the `cdkVirtualFor`. That does fix the issue, but it also completely defeats the purpose of virtual scroll and unsurprisingly all the performance gain from virtual scroll seems to be gone when using this.